# How can I get the username from a WCF AuthenticationService?

Tags: c#, wcf

how can I get the name of the logged in user when the result of `AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()` is true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally i would find WCF security information from ServiceSecurityContext.Current. Try ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the Thead.CurrentPrincipal?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name

Answer (score 0):

`WebContext.Current.Authentication`?